# Can't change language to 'zh-CN' in android?

Tags: react-calendar

i console the

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat.supportedLocalesOf(['zh-cn', 'zh-tw', 'zh']));
```

and shows

```
['zh-CN', 'zh-TW', 'zh']
```

however, when I set the `locale` of react-calendar to `'zh'`, the language is still English?

update: when I didn't set the 'locale' of react-calendar and console the default language of the browser by executing `navigator.language`
the console is

```
zh-CN
```

however, the language is still English?

update: i check the `arial-label` attribute of `<adbr></adbr>` and found it is `Tue Nov 30 2021 15:27:54 GMT+0800 (CST)` which is strange since it is `2021年8月5日` on PC. And i console the `locale` in `formatDay` function, the console is `'zh-CN'`.

Answer (score 0):

I check carefully and found it is the problem of browser of THE APP self, not the problem of the `react-calendar`